# prevent to close android virtual device manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Each time i test my application, I accidently close `android emulator` started by `AVD` manager. I want to prevent myself doing this.
At least emulator can **prompt** a warning message asking if i really want to close it or not. How can i do that?
You know emulator spends so much time when it is being started. So everytime i close it, i have to wait for it again to be started. And I am writing these additional lines because they don't accept my question to post because it is not a good quality.

Answer (score 0):

yeah that is a problem we all face instead of minimizing it we accidentally close it.
so my solution will be that avoid using emulator and use android mobile for running your app in developer mode

Comment: this should be post as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's that's the main problem of adb, i reccomend you to use another emulator.

I use this myself for a long time and it is really fast and have a lot of cool functionalities, i already saved many time with it:
[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Mobile for running instead of emulator

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using HAXM? It speeds up the boot time for your emulator significantly that accidentally closing might not seem like a big deal :)

You can download it from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

Comment: I use Windows XP which is not supported by HAXM. Only Windows 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit), Windows 7 (32/64-bit), Windows Vista* (32/64-bit) supported. I don't want an external plug in by the way.